# Matplotlib Row heights table property

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have tried every command and piece of documentation I can find. How do I set the the height of the rows here.

```
from pylab import *

# Create a figure
fig1 = figure(1)
ax1_1 = fig1.add_subplot(111)

# Add a table with some numbers....

tab = [[1.0000, 3.14159], [1, 2], [2, 1]]

# Format table numbers as string
tab_2 = [['%.2f' % j for j in i] for i in tab]

y_table = plt.table(cellText=tab_2,colLabels=['Col A','Col B'], colWidths = [.5]*2, loc='center')
y_table.set_fontsize(34)


show()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could use `ytable.scale`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tab = [[1.0000, 3.14159], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
tab2 = [['%.2f' % j for j in i] for i in tab]

ytable = plt.table(cellText=tab2, colLabels=['Col A','Col B'], 
                    colWidths=[.5]*2, loc='center')
ytable.set_fontsize(34)
ytable.scale(1, 4)
plt.show()
```

yields

[image]

Answer (score 22):

The above answer works, but is kinda a cheat and doesn't provide any flexibility, eg. you can't make the top row higher than the others.  You can explicitly set the height of each cell in a row with the `get_celld()` method and `set_height()`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
tab = [[1.0000, 3.14159], [1, 2], [2, 1]]
tab2 = [['%.2f' % j for j in i] for i in tab]
colLabels=['Col A','Col B']
ytable = ax.table(cellText=tab2, colLabels=colLabels, 
                    colWidths=[.5]*2, loc='center')

cellDict = ytable.get_celld()
for i in range(0,len(colLabels)):
    cellDict[(0,i)].set_height(.3)
    for j in range(1,len(tab)+1):
        cellDict[(j,i)].set_height(.2)

ytable.set_fontsize(25)
ax.axis('off')
ax.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is simpler than what @JuneSkeeter proposed *if* you know which row you want to be larger. It avoids having to loop twice. This makes the first row (i.e. row index 0) `0.3`.

```
for r in range(0, len(colLabels)):
    cell = ytable[0, r]
    cell.set_height(0.3)
```

Comment: I prefer this way, because it's more flexible in my opinion. `cell.set_height(.3)`