# Matplotlib Pyplot table - how to vertically center text after using scale to make cells taller?

Tags: matplotlib

Based on this [Matplotlib Row heights table property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972524/matplotlib-row-heights-table-property) answer I was able to use the Matplotlib Pyplot `table` `scale` property to change cell heights to add some whitespace buffer above and below the text.  Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colLabels = ['col 0', 'col 1', 'col 2']
rowLabels = ['row 0', 'row 1', 'row 2']

tableData = [['123', '123', '123'],
             ['123', '123', '123'],
             ['123', '123', '123']]

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.title.set_text('Table Title')

myTable = ax.table(cellText=tableData, rowLabels=rowLabels, colLabels=colLabels,
                   cellLoc='center', rowLoc='center', loc='center')
myTable.auto_set_font_size(False)
myTable.set_fontsize(12)
myTable.scale(1, 2)

plt.show()

print('\n' + 'done !!' + '\n')
```

Result:

[image]

Notice however that the cell text is closer to the top of the cell than the bottom.  Is there a way to vertically center the text within cells with this method or any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `scale(1, 2)` adjustment results obtained in the referenced responses have an impact. If you adjust manually, the scale is about (1,1.4). To set the scale and position the string, you need to readjust the height in the second answer. `cellDict` contains the index and cell object, so set the height of that cell.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

colLabels = ['col 0', 'col 1', 'col 2']
rowLabels = ['row 0', 'row 1', 'row 2']

tableData = [['123', '123', '123'],
             ['123', '123', '123'],
             ['123', '123', '123']]

ax.set_axis_off()
ax.title.set_text('Table Title')

myTable = ax.table(cellText=tableData, rowLabels=rowLabels, colLabels=colLabels,
                   cellLoc='center', rowLoc='center', loc='center')
myTable.auto_set_font_size(False)
myTable.set_fontsize(12)
myTable.scale(1, 2)

cellDict = myTable.get_celld()
for cell in cellDict:
    #print(cell)
    cellDict[cell].set_height(0.2)

plt.show()
```

[image]